# Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: ab_price, amazon_price, desc, fk_price, id, is_avl, launch_date,

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am getting this error but, I don't have name in my ORM class, i was expecting it to be fine.
before this, I had changed the name field to p_model and now name is nowhere in the code

```py
models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    p_model = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Model')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Description')
    launch_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Launch Date')
    amazon_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Amazon Price')
    fk_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Flipkart Price')
    sd_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='SnapDeal Price')
    ab_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Alibaba Price')
    is_avl = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='In Stock')

views.py
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addproduct(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            usrn = request.user.username
            wall = wallet.objects.get(username=usrn)
            bal = wall.Balance
            wallet.objects.update(username=usrn, Balance=bal + 5)
            newbal = get_bal(request)
            messages.success(request,
                             f'Product has been added successfully, Your current wallet Balance is {newbal} try '
                             f'adding more')
            return redirect('addproduct')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Data")
    else:
        form = Addproduct()
        bal = get_bal(request)
        usrn = request.user.username
        return render(request, 'register/addproduct.html', {'form': form, 'bal': bal, 'usr': usrn})

forms.py
class Addproduct(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('__all__') 
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to migrate model changes to your DB.
Use `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`. You should do this after every model change.

Comment: You're very welcome. How about an upvote and answer accept?:)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the most recently updated .py extention file from your app migration folder and then try migrations again by `python manage.py makemigrations` and then try `python manage.py migrate`. If the same error occurs again, then (repeat the process) again go to your migrations folder and again delete the most recently updated file. 
I recommend you to make a backup copy of your project before trying this solution